# Zariski density of a matrix semigroup generated by Jordan blocks

Tags: semigroups, random-matrices, divisors-algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

In the field of random matrix products, it seems a lot of theorems which give nice statistical properties (central limit theorem, large deviation, etc.) assume—among other things—a Zariski density property.

The problem is, I have no clue how to prove Zariski density at all!

Here is a toy example in two dimensions: Let $$A_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right), \qquad A_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right). $$

### Question:

Is the semigroup generated by these two matrices,

$$ \left\langle A_1, A_2 \right\rangle  = \bigcup_{n=1}^∞ \big\{A_{i_1}A_{i_2}\cdots A_{i_n}\;:\; (i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n)\in \{1,2\}^n\big\},$$

Zariski dense in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$? In other words, must every polynomial in 4 variables which vanishes on this semigroup vanish on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$?